# Add/Remove CSS Class with JS Loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation menu that displays a group of notes from the clicked topic. The note can either have class `note` if it is visible or class `invisible` if it is hidden. I want only the notes from the topic clicked to show.

The problem is that some notes from other topics are also being shown. Even though the length of `thisTopic` is always 2.

I am new to JavaScript so maybe there is an error in my loop? Thanks in advance :)

```js
function openTopic(evt, topicName) {
    var allNotes, thisTopic;
    
  /* Hide all notes */
    allNotes = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
    for (i = 0; i < allNotes.length; i++) {
    allNotes[i].classList.add("invisible");
        allNotes[i].classList.remove("note");
    }
    
  /* Show notes with correct topic */
    thisTopic = document.getElementsByClassName(topicName);
    for (i = 0; i < thisTopic.length; i++) {
        thisTopic[i].classList.add("note");
        thisTopic[i].classList.remove("invisible");
    }
}
```

```css
.box {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #999;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.note {
    display: block;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class='box'>
    <h3>Navigation</h3>
    <ul>
        <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic1')">Topic 1</li>
    <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic2')">Topic 2</li>
    <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic3')">Topic 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <section class='note topic1 box'>
    <p>First topic 1 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic1 box'>
    <p>Second topic 1 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic2 box'>
    <p>First topic 2 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic2 box'>
    <p>Second topic 2 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic3 box'>
    <p>First topic 3 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic3 box'>
    <p>Second topic 3 note</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- You're removing the `note` class from elements.
- You're not giving elements that should be hidden by default the `invisible` class.

```js
function openTopic(evt, topicName) {
    var allNotes, thisTopic;
    
  /* Hide all notes */
    allNotes = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
    for (i = 0; i < allNotes.length; i++)
        allNotes[i].classList.add("invisible");
    
  /* Show notes with correct topic */
    thisTopic = document.getElementsByClassName(topicName);
    for (i = 0; i < thisTopic.length; i++)
        thisTopic[i].classList.remove("invisible");
}
```

```css
.box {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #999;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.note {
  display: block;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.note.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class='box'>
    <h3>Navigation</h3>
    <ul>
        <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic1')">Topic 1</li>
        <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic2')">Topic 2</li>
        <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic3')">Topic 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <section class='note topic1 box'>
    <p>First topic 1 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic1 box'>
    <p>Second topic 1 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic2 box invisible'>
    <p>First topic 2 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic2 box invisible'>
    <p>Second topic 2 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic3 box invisible'>
    <p>First topic 3 note</p>
  </section>
  <section class='note topic3 box invisible'>
    <p>Second topic 3 note</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

With that in mind however, I'd strongly recommend a few things:

- Reverse your logic. (Hide by default, then activate.)
- Use the `id` attribute at a higher level instead of `class` for `topic#`.

### Reverse Your Logic

Currently, you have 3 topics with 2 notes each. Imagine instead, that you have 5 topics with 5 notes each. With your current logic, you'll need to assign the `invisible` class, by default to 20 `section` elements. Instead, use an `active` class and you'll only need to assign it to 5 `section` elements:

```
.note {
    display: none;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.note.active { display: block }
```

You can see how this impacts your snippet below when taken to a larger scale:

```js
function openTopic(evt, topicName) {
    var allNotes, thisTopic;

    /* Hide all notes */
    allNotes = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
    for (i = 0; i < allNotes.length; i++)
        allNotes[i].classList.remove("active");

    /* Show notes with correct topic */
    thisTopic = document.getElementsByClassName(topicName);
    for (i = 0; i < thisTopic.length; i++)
        thisTopic[i].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.box {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #999;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.note {
    display: none;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.note.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class='box'>
    <h3>Navigation</h3>
    <ul>
        <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic1')">Topic 1</li>
        <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic2')">Topic 2</li>
        <li onClick="openTopic(event, 'topic3')">Topic 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>
    <section class='note topic1 box active'>
        <p>Topic 1 Note 1</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic1 box active'>
        <p>Topic 1 Note 2</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic1 box active'>
        <p>Topic 1 Note 3</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic1 box active'>
        <p>Topic 1 Note 4</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic1 box active'>
        <p>Topic 1 Note 5</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic2 box'>
        <p>Topic 2 Note 1</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic2 box'>
        <p>Topic 2 Note 2</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic2 box'>
        <p>Topic 2 Note 3</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic2 box'>
        <p>Topic 2 Note 4</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic2 box'>
        <p>Topic 2 Note 5</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic3 box'>
        <p>Topic 3 Note 1</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic3 box'>
        <p>Topic 3 Note 2</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic3 box'>
        <p>Topic 3 Note 3</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic3 box'>
        <p>Topic 3 Note 4</p>
    </section>
    <section class='note topic3 box'>
        <p>Topic 3 Note 5</p>
    </section>
</main>
```

### Use `id` and grouping

It's common practice to group elements within a parent element. In your case, I recommend encapsulating your `section` elements into a `div` that is designed for each topic using the `id` attribute:

```
<div id="topic1Notes" class="topic-container active">
    <section class="note box">
        <p>Topic 1 Note 1</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

### Use Bootstrap

If using third party tools like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) aren't out of the question, they already handle this and provide very easy to follow code for doing so, taking the leg work off of you:

```css
.box {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #999;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.note {
  display: block;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.note.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Topic 1</button>
        <button class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Topic 2</button>
        <button class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Topic 3</button>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
        <section for="topic1" class='note topic1 box'>
            <p>First topic 1 note</p>
        </section>
        <section class='note topic1 box'>
            <p>Second topic 1 note</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
        <section class='note topic2 box'>
            <p>First topic 2 note</p>
        </section>
        <section class='note topic2 box'>
            <p>Second topic 2 note</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
        <section class='note topic3 box'>
            <p>First topic 3 note</p>
        </section>
        <section class='note topic3 box'>
            <p>Second topic 3 note</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Best of luck!

Comment: @JessicaFrancis no problem! :D